# rror-creating-bean-with-name-springsecurityfilterchain

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Description
I could not load the JSP file in my spring boot program. Giving the filter chain error. What should I do to resolve the error? Below I am attaching the login.JSP file, pom file, and my security config File.

the error

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'login.jsp?error' is not a valid redirect URL

pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

securityConfigFile

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

         http
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("**/secured/**").permitAll() 
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .formLogin().loginPage("login.jsp").defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html", true).permitAll()
             .and()
         .logout()                                    
             .permitAll();
http.csrf().disable();
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value=""/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Log in with your credentials</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <form method="POST" action="/login" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-heading">Log in</h2>

        <div class="form-group ">
            <span></span>
            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                   autofocus="true"/>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
            <span></span>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `spring-security-core` dpenedency and add `spring-boot-starter-security` instead. Next to that you shouldn't expose your JSP's directly but have a controller for that. So your view should be `login` nog `login.jsp`. Add a view controller for this and make sure you have configured the view resolution correctly. That being said Spring Boot doesn't advocate the use of JSPs as those have quite some limitations in embedded systems.

Comment: how can iconfigure the view controller?